# WPF - Setting DataContext for a Trigger's setter

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, datacontext, datatrigger

I have a `DataTrigger` that I recently refactored.  It used to have the `DataContext` set to be a `ListBoxItem`.  Now it is a `ContentPresenter`.

Here is the code:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
                <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Id"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="loc:Main.IsCurrentItemEnabledChanged" Value="True"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

In the `OnChange` of `IsCurrentItemEnabledChanged` I can see that I can get at the `ListBoxItem` with the following code (in the code behind):

```
listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)Main.Instance.lstQueryResults.ItemContainerGenerator.
               ContainerFromItem(((ContentPresenter)d).Content);
```

However, there is no way that I can see to set the `DataContext` such that my `Setter` for `IsEnabled` will set the enabled status of the `ListBoxItem` rather than the `ContentPresenter`.

(I would do it in the `OnChange` of `IsCurrentItemEnabledChanged`, but that property is already a bit of a hack and it will not re-enable the item when the trigger is set to false.)

Any ideas?

---

It was suggested that I provide more to provide context:

Here is my XAML for the templates.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnTemplate">
    <Border Name="ItemBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2">
        <WrapPanel>                   
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Name" Converter="{StaticResource GetVisibilityOfColumnTitles}"/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="RowTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#D4D4FF">
        <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}, Path=ActualWidth}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Background>
                <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Type" Converter="{StaticResource WorkItemTypeToColorConverter}" />
            </Grid.Background>

            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                      Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" Name="chkIsSelected" />

            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnTemplate}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>


            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="btnPick" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource roundButton}" Width="15" Height="15" Tag="{Binding WorkItemForColumn.Id}" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                <Path Fill="DarkBlue">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="2,0" IsClosed="True">
                                <LineSegment Point="7,5"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="2,10"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="2,2" IsClosed="True">
                                <LineSegment Point="5,5"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="2,8"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
                    <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Id"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="loc:Main.IsCurrentItemEnabledChanged" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is the XAML for the List Box:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Button.Click="PickWorkItem_Click" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RowTemplate}"  Name="lstQueryResults" SelectionChanged="lstQueryResults_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

The DataContext is set in the Code like so:

```
private void ChangeQueryResultListSource(WorkItemCollection queryResults, bool b)
{
    // Un-hook the selection event while we change the ItemsSource
    Form.ToggleOnSelectEvent(false);

    // This sets the DataContext
    QueryDisplay = GetDisplayValues(queryResults);

    Form.QueryResultListSource = QueryDisplay;
    // Rewire the selection events back in
    Form.ToggleOnSelectEvent(true);


    foreach (WorkItem item in Pad.Keys)
    {
        Form.SelectQueryResultItem(item);
    }
}

private List<List<WorkItemColumn>> GetDisplayValues(WorkItemCollection queryResults)
{
    var result = new List<List<WorkItemColumn>>();
    foreach (WorkItem workItem in queryResults)
    {
        var row = GetQueryColumns(queryResults.DisplayFields, workItem);
        result.Add(row);
    }
    return result;
}

private List<WorkItemColumn> GetQueryColumns(DisplayFieldList fields, WorkItem workItem)
{
    var row = new List<WorkItemColumn>();
    foreach (FieldDefinition column in fields)
    {
        var workItemColumn = new WorkItemColumn { Name = column.Name, Value = workItem[column.Name], WorkItemForColumn = workItem };
        row.Add(workItemColumn);
    }

    return row;
}
```

`WorkItemColumn` is a class with a Name-Value pair and a reference to the data (a `WorkItem` object).

Comment: I might be the only one but I'm a bit confused by your question. "However, there is no way that I can see to set the DataContext such that my Setter for IsEnabled will set the enabled status of the ListBoxItem rather than the ContentPresenter."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer, but you should move the trigger and setter logic for `IsEnabled` back to the `ListBoxItem` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
                    <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Id"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```